# Can you explain the operation of this RC network for a crystal oscillator?

Tags: crystal, remote-control

I am trying to work out what the RC network in the circuit below does and how it works. The circuit output is fed as input to a CD4060 binary counter. According to what I have read, the signal from the crystal into the CD4060 must be bounce-less and noise free. Is that what the RC network is doing? How does it work?

[image: Crystal RC network]

Comment: [Crystal load capacitance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527486/crystal-load-capacitance-for-low-power-applications/527505#527505). [Crystal resonator drive level](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532146/crystal-resonator-drive-level/532168#532168). [Crystal oscillator load capacitance, again](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250608/crystal-oscillator-load-capacitance-again/250645#250645).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crystal load capacitance for low power applications](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527486/crystal-load-capacitance-for-low-power-applications) (or any of the other two listed above?)

Comment: Yeah. The answers and comments answer my question.

Comment: Mario - are you really able to explain how the RC network works and how it can fulfill the oscillation condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10M provides the DC input self-centering bias so the CMOS can amplify the signal near Vdd/2 by virtue of negative feedback from the internal CMOS inverter.

The two C’s are designed to match the crystal load rating for centre frequency. (C1//C2)

The 33k reduces the current so that the internal crystal lattice only draws <50uW due to the high density of power limitations on the crystal lattice inside. It does not affect the frequency and the voltage gain in the CMOS now working as an analog amplifier that limits to a square wave.

Comment: The crystal lattice might resonate the frequency voltage to some kV value and thus reactive VAR power and internal ESR creates heat from >50uW that can damage the molecules of quartz. From motional capacitance vibrations.  Any more questions? They have entire books on the physics over 40 yrs ago

Answer (score 0):

Very often, a crystal is operated at one of this resonant frequencies - however, not in this case !! Outside the frequencies for series- or parallel resonance the crystal can work as a capacitor or as a high-Q inductor Lq. The latter applies in the shown example.

As a consequence, we have a frequency-dependent feedback circuit which produces at a certain frequency **180deg phase shift** which is necessary to fulfill the **oscillation condition.** (unity loop gain).

Verification: We have a **3rd-order lowpass** in classical ladder structure:

**33k-32pF-Lq-15pF**.

The maximum phase shift is (for very large frequencies) -270 deg and there is one single frequency with a phase shift of -180deg. (as required).

As explained by Tony Stewart, the 10megohm resistor provides negative DC feedback for operational point stabilization.